# Vagrant-up not working getting an error using arrikto/minikf

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, minikube, kubeflow

trying to download minikubeflow but I just keep getting this issue were it hangs it and eventually i get an error after about an hour.I installed virtual box like the instructions say to but it still can not be found. Any insight on what the reason may be for this issue?

```
$ vagrant init arrikto/minikf
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

jared@DESKTOP-JQH7K9J MINGW64 ~/Documents/minikf
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
**==> default: Box 'arrikto/minikf' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...**
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'arrikto/minikf'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/arrikto/minikf
==> default: Adding box 'arrikto/minikf' (v20200305.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/arrikto/boxes/minikf/versions/20200305.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
Download redirected to host: storage.googleapis.com
Progress: 4% (Rate: 6723k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:44:32)
```

Comment: Do as written here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/debugging.html and take a look at the debug logs to see what's happening in the background.

Comment: "default: Box 'arrikto/minikf' could not be found. Attempting to find and install..." this line is the issue but I am not sure why it can not find it.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Apologizes-----

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection and make sure you have a lot of free space. I faced the same issue but it works fine if there is good amount of free space and faster internet connection.